# Angular unit test ActivatedRoute params subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

Lets say I have a subscription to route params in my component:

```
this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
    // what the params object holds
    // params.id1 params.id2

    // what the current route looks like
    //localhost/params.id1/params.id2
});
```

How would I unit test `params.id2` in Angular? Example: i want to test if params.id2 > 0

Currently I have done this:

```
// top of the describe
let route: ActivatedRoute;

//inside the TestBed.configureTestingModule
providers: [
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute,
      useValue: {
        params: of({
          id1: 1,
          id2: 0,
        }),
      },
    },
  ],

route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);

it('shouldn't be zero', () => {
    // i want to check if params.id2 is not zero

    expect(params.id2).not.toBe(0);
});
```

I don't have any experience using unit tests. Do i have to subscribe to the route.params like i do in the component, or how do i implement the test method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It will be zero because you're providing a static value of zero in the `useValue`.

To be able to change it, I would use a `BehaviorSubject` where it is an observable and it can be changed in the future by using `next`.

```
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
....
// top of the describe
let route: ActivatedRoute;
const paramsSubject = new BehaviorSubject({
  id1: 1,
  id2: 0,
});

//inside the TestBed.configureTestingModule
providers: [
    {
      provide: ActivatedRoute,
      useValue: {
        params: paramsSubject
      },
    },
  ]

route = TestBed.inject(ActivatedRoute);

it('should be zero', (done) => { // add done to let Jasmine know when you're done with the test
  route.params.subscribe(params => {
    expect(params.id2).toBe(0);
    done();
  });
});

it('should not be zero', (done) => {
  paramsSubject.next({ id1: 1, id2: 3});
  route.params.subscribe(params => {
    expect(params.id2).not.toBe(0);
    done();
  });
});
```

But ideally those tests written are not good. You should be testing what happens inside of the `subscribe` in your component and assert that what happens does indeed happen.

Comment: I know they aren't good tests, they are just dummy tests. But is there a way I could do it without subscribing? For example, would spyOn work and if it would how would I use it (`spyOn('route.params', 'subscribe).and.returnValue({id1: 1, id2: 0})`)

Comment: No that won't work. You can only `spyOn` methods/functions of a class and `params` is an instance variable that is an observable and so `spyOn` won't work.

Comment: thank you! I totally forgot about behaviourSubject to init an observer with values!!!